# Expand data to display chart

Tags: key-value, kql, expand

I have table like:

```
let tbl = datatable (metric:string, ct:int, details:dynamic)
[ 
    "Some1",5, dynamic([
        {
        "Key": "NO",
        "Value": 4
        },
        {
        "Key": "CA",
        "Value": 1
        }
    ]),
    "Some2",10, dynamic([
        {
        "Key": "GB",
        "Value": 10
        }])
];
```

Which is following data:

```
metric | ct  | details
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Some1  | 5   | [{"Key":"NO","Value":4},{"Key":"CA","Value":1}]
Some2  | 10  | [{"Key":"GB","Value":10}]
```

I wanna reduce it to finall table (*):

```
 metric   | ct  
 ----------------
 Some1-NO | 4   
 Some1-CA | 1
 Some1    | 5
 Some2-BG | 10
 Some2    | 10
```

I expanded the collection of k-v pairs, but I do not know how to progress to acheive (*.

```
metric | details | ct
-----------------------------------------
Some1  | 5       | {"Key":"NO","Value":4}
Some1  | 5       | {"Key":"CA","Value":1}
Some2  | 10      | {"Key":"GB","Value":10}
```

What could be the next step/operator?

```
tbl
| mv-expand details
| ??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let tbl = datatable (metric:string, ct:int, details:dynamic)
[ 
    "Some1" ,5  ,dynamic([{"Key": "NO", "Value": 4},{"Key": "CA", "Value": 1}])
   ,"Some2" ,10 ,dynamic([{"Key": "GB", "Value": 10}])
];
union 
   (tbl 
    | project metric, ct
    )
  ,(tbl 
    | mv-expand details 
    | project metric = strcat(metric, "-", tostring(details.Key))
             ,ct = toint(details.Value)
   )
```

| metric | ct |
| --- | --- |
| Some1 | 5 |
| Some2 | 10 |
| Some1-NO | 4 |
| Some1-CA | 1 |
| Some2-GB | 10 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3VQwWoCMRC9L%20w/DDllYSyu2MuKh7aHHgr2IHgRDzE7SEo2KzoWpfrvjolaBZ1AILw3L%2089Tww89zCE2rCcuSfQDfHK2Wotd1ggWK5cYISa2Di/rupdMI2zRZ5NIc9ARo3bhkoF%20AqAZ1hP/9QX7VQFavStENTE%20A3Js3/AK/LxdouUh1kRBTEK9kSw7D4S/Hy/W%20vGvdkgzzbBtSGZ0qdYyd4elqv2hyxDSnaKlJD4Hd5Rm98ObZcm1Je8T0SkMinIGtYXUdURV9ym2vR5%200UsFynV/6CoDIUqtV55MU0iFkcxEST4lgEAAA==)

Answer (score 1):

```
let tbl = datatable (metric:string, ct:int, details:dynamic)
[ 
    "Some1" ,5  ,dynamic([{"Key": "NO", "Value": 4},{"Key": "CA", "Value": 1}])
   ,"Some2" ,10 ,dynamic([{"Key": "GB", "Value": 10}])
];
tbl
| mv-expand details = array_concat(details, pack_array(bag_pack("Value", ct)))
| project metric = strcat(metric, iff(isnull(details.Key), "", "-"), tostring(details.Key))
         ,ct = toint(details.Value)
```

| metric | ct |
| --- | --- |
| Some1-NO | 4 |
| Some1-CA | 1 |
| Some1 | 5 |
| Some2-GB | 10 |
| Some2 | 10 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA22QwWrDMAyG74G8g/DJBnU0Y7tk9LDtsMNgOwx2KSU4jlu8OU5I3LGw9d0n22lZoTIYy5I+/l9We/C1hRU00tOprQbeaj8YVY50ux2C8qVxHqHRXho7ls3kZGuUyLM15BlQsLeu1QUDvAXAuczXP+xZT6wE9vLKENi7tHtN6c0BT5XH+/+V4rAREYgReE3AYnkJ+PRwNraMc5u7PCMrefYL7ddCf/fSNUfN5E8Og5wq1TklPZ+/EXqpPqtY4rXcVSHlMzgYF0IEXj90H1p5SIshGK0mYFKOYLZbbka3t/ZIviKlgjQGnQtGL9+ldZ41JLcpkPgraqNVn3qiEPEHer1ZX6QBAAA=)